# Create a words histogram of a given string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a code that given a string (`txt`), will print a histogram that contains the number of occurrences of each word in it and the word itself.

A word is defined to be a sequence of chars separated by one space or more.

The code is working, I just want to see if I can improve it.

```
def PrintWordsOccurence(txt):
    lst = [x for x in txt.split(' ') if x != ' ' and x != '']
    newlst = list(dict.fromkeys(lst))
    for item in newlst:
        print("[{0}] {1}".format(lst.count(item),item))
```

An input-output example:

```
>> PrintWordsOccurence("hello code review!  this is  my   code")

[1] hello
[2] code
[1] review!
[1] this
[1] is
[1] my
```

The first line creates a list with all words, there will be duplicates in it, so to remove them, I  turn the list into a dictionary and then I turn it back to a list.
In the end, for each item in the list, I print the number of its occurrences in the original string and the item itself.

The time complexity of the code is \$\Theta(n^2)\$

Any suggestions to improve the code?

Answer (score 15):

#### str.split method without arguments

It does the same filtering as you do. Just skip ' ' argument.

#### list(dict.fromkeys(list comprehension))

It looks overburdened, right? You can create a set of list comprehension as well:

```
newlst = list({x for x in txt.split()})
```

or just

```
newlst = list(set(txt.split()))
```

but the best way is

#### collections.Counter

You're reinventing it with worse time complexity.

#### Format strings

f-strings look better (but it depends on your task).

#### Function name

[PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) advices to use lower case with underscores: print_words_occurence

#### All together

```
from collections import Counter
def print_words_occurence(txt):
   for word, count in Counter(txt.split()).items():
       print(f"[{count}] {word}")
```

Also consider dividing an algorithmic part and input/output - like yielding a pair (word, count) from the function and outputting it somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

This can be improved by implementing a two-line, basic [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort) in core python:

```
def print_words_occurence(txt):
    wdict = dict()
    for w in txt.strip().split(): 
        wdict[w] = wdict.get(w, 0) + 1
    # just to print results
    [print(f"[{wdict[k]}] {k}") for k in wdict.keys()]
```

The run time is O(n) if the final dict isn't sorted. [If it is sorted, it's still O(n+k).] I don't think anything can be more efficient.